# How to increase number in range set till it gives a specific answer?

Tags: matlab, runge-kutta

I've wrote a rungekutta code and there is a specific x range that it should calculate up to it. The problem is that the prof. wants a code that keeps on adding up by itself till it reaches the required answer.

I tried using the 'if' function but it only works once and no more (thus, even creating a mismatch in array lengths.

Code:

```
h=0.5;% step size
z=0.5;
x = 0:h:z;% the range of x
y = zeros(1,length(x)); 
y(1) = 50;% initial condition
F_xy = @(t,x) (37.5-3.5*x);%function



for i=1:(length(x)-1)% calculation loop
    k_1 = F_xy(x(i),y(i));
    k_2 = F_xy(x(i)+h,y(i)+h*k_1);

    y(i+1) = y(i) + (h/2)*(k_1+k_2);% main equation
    if y(i+1)>11
        x=0:h:z+1;

    end

end



disp (y(i+1))
```

Error of arrays length (shows that if function only works once)

```
   41.4063

 Error using plot
Vectors must be the same length.

Error in code6rungekutta2ndorder (line 30)
plot(x,y), grid on
```

it should keep on increasing by +1 in the 'z' variable till the answer of y(i+1) is less than 11. (correct z should be 9.5)

Comment: try a `while` loop until your conditions are met.

Comment: @medicine_man the `while` loop loads forever and does not stop. could it be something wrong with my code?

Comment: Potentially. A [`while`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html) loop continues until a condition is met. This means that if you run into an infinite loop, the condition for the while will have to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @medicine_man suggested, you need a `while` loop:

```
h=0.5;% step size
z=0.5;
x = 0;
y = 50;% initial condition
F_xy = @(t,x) (37.5-3.5*x);%function


m = 0;
while y(m+1) > 11
    m = m+1;
    x = x+h;
    k_1 = F_xy(x,y(m));
    k_2 = F_xy(x+h,y(m)+h*k_1);

    y(m+1) = y(m) + (h/2)*(k_1+k_2);% main equation

end

figure;
plot(0:h:x, y);
```

Your terminate condition, which is `y(m+1) > 11`, is checked at the beginning of each iteration of the `while` loop. In the loop, you can increment the value of `x` and update your `y` array. The loop runs until the terminate condition is met.

The result of the above code:

[image]